# Visual Studio setup project condition for registry not working

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, windows-installer

I have created an setup project that needs to create a registry key in HKLM.
As a condition for this, I have written "NOT (MYCONDITION=1)", so that if the user defines MYCONDITION=1 during command line execution of the msi, then the registry key is not written.
msiexec /i mymsi.msi /passive /MYCONDITION=1

This is however ignored by the MSI file and the registry key is still written.

I have set the exact same condition on a file in the Files System view, and here it works. So if the user has this MyCondition=1, the file is not copied to the installation folder.

Can any of you come up with a reason why I experience this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: Do you also have this property in a dialog box (such as Checkboxes) in the setup project? I also assume that you are looking in the WoW6432 registry if this is an x86 setup project (TargetPlatform in project property window).

Comment: No I do not have a checkbox that has that value because it will only be a command line option. I assume that when I enter it in command line, then it is defined and can be checked for in a condition. And I do not need ot search in wow6432, because I am not missing a registry entry. On the contrary, I have one two many entries and that is not expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of getting it to work. Instead of putting the condition on the parent key of the values I want to add, I set the condition on each of the registry values, and that worked fine.
Make sure however to have the "AlwaysCreate" property to false on the Key, so that it is not created if its child values are not created